# Spring Async not working (Async Mail send)

Tags: spring, asynchronous, configuration, sendmail

I am using spring and hibernate and Want to send Async Mail But is it not working in my case. I read lot many thinks from SO but those solutions are not working for me.

package com.kayoner.hesk.daos;

```
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.velocity.VelocityContext;
import org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncResult;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils;

@Component
public class SendMail {

    public static Logger logger=Logger.getLogger(SendMail.class);


    public SendMail() {

    }








    /**
     * @param host
     * @param port
     * @param senderEmail
     * @param passwordParam
     * @param receiverEmail
     * @param subject
     * @param content
     * @return
     * @throws MessagingException
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException
     */
    @Async
    public void sendMailGeneral(String host, String port, String senderEmail,
            String passwordParam, String receiverEmail, String replyTo,String subject,
            String content) throws MessagingException,
            UnsupportedEncodingException {

        try {
            logger.info("THREAD SLEEP FOR 3000 MS");
            Thread.sleep(3000);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }





    /**
     * @param input
     * @param variables
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public String parseTemplates(String input, Map<String, Object> variables)
            throws Exception { 

            Velocity.init();

            VelocityContext vc = new VelocityContext();


            if (variables != null) {
                Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> itr =
                    variables.entrySet().iterator();

                while (itr.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry<String, Object> entry = itr.next();

                    String key = entry.getKey();
                    Object value = entry.getValue();



                    if (key != null) {

                        vc.put(key, value);
                    }
                }
            }


            StringWriter output = new StringWriter();

            Velocity.evaluate(vc, output, "LOG", input);

            return output.toString();
        }


}
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd
">



    <context:property-placeholder
        location="classpath:jdbc.properties,classpath:domain.properties" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.kayoner" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"  />



    <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/,/images/dashboard/" />


    <task:annotation-driven executor="executor"
        scheduler="scheduler"   />
    <task:scheduler id="scheduler" pool-size="10" />
    <task:executor id="executor" queue-capacity="100" />




    <util:map id="datasources">
        <entry key="tenant1" value-ref="dataSource" />
        <!-- <entry key="tenant2" value-ref="dataSource2"/> -->
        <!-- <entry key="company" value-ref="company"/> -->
    </util:map>

    <bean id="datasourcesCls" class="com.kayoner.multytanecy.DatasourcesCls">
        <property name="datasources" ref="datasources"></property>
    </bean>



    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">

        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />


    </bean>


    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="validator" class="org.springmodules.validation.bean.BeanValidator" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />

    </bean>

    <!-- This is for the server side validation for the data -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven
        content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager"></mvc:annotation-driven>

    <bean id="webSessionTenantIdentifierResolver"
        class="com.kayoner.multytanecy.WebSessionCurrentTenantIdentifierResolver"
        scope="request">
        <aop:scoped-proxy />
    </bean>

    <bean id="simpleTenantConnectionProvider"
        class="com.kayoner.multytanecy.SimpleMultiTenantConnectionProvider">
        <property name="dataSourceMap" ref="datasources" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="com.kayoner.multytanecy.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="dataSourceMap" ref="datasources" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>




                <value>com.kayoner.hesk.models.Tickets</value>
                <value>com.kayoner.hesk.models.Replies</value>




            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <map>
                <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="${hibernate.dialect}"></entry>
                <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"></entry>
                <entry key="hibernate.multiTenancy" value="DATABASE" />
                <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
                <entry key="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver" value-ref="webSessionTenantIdentifierResolver" />
                <entry key="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider"
                    value-ref="simpleTenantConnectionProvider" />
            </map>
        </property>

        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>hibernate.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        <property name="autodetectDataSource" value="false" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="customizationSettingsDAO"
        class="com.kayoner.companysettings.companysettingsdaos.CustomizationSettingsDAO"></bean>
    <bean id="customizationSettingsService"
        class="com.kayoner.companysettings.companysettingsserviceImpl.CustomizationSettingsServiceImpl"></bean>
    <!-- <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver"> 
        <property name="mediaTypes"> <map> <entry key="html" value="text/html" /> 
        <entry key="json" value="application/json" /> </map> </property> <property 
        name="defaultViews"> <list> <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView"> 
        <property name="prefixJson" value="true" /> </bean> </list> </property> </bean> 
        <bean id="jacksonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"> 
        </bean> <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"> 
        <property name="messageConverters"> <list> <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter" 
        /> </list> </property> </bean> -->

    <bean id="contentNegotiationManager"
        class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <value>
                json=application/json
                xml=application/xml
            </value>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />
    </bean>


    <!-- bind your messages.properties -->
    <!-- <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
        id="messageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages" />
    </bean> -->

    <!-- Configure the multipart resolver -->
    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="200000000" />

    </bean>

     <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean> 
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="language" />
    </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>


    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
          <property name="cookieName" value="myAppLocaleCookie"></property>
        <property name="cookieMaxAge" value="3600"></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- <bean id="handlerMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
        </property>
    </bean> -->

    <security:global-method-security
        jsr250-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled">
        <security:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler" />
    </security:global-method-security>
    <bean id="webExpressionHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler" />

    <bean id="expressionHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
        <property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="permissionEvaluator" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="user" class="com.kayoner.usermanage.usermodel.User">
        <aop:scoped-proxy />
    </bean>

    <bean id="permissionEvaluator" class="com.kayoner.security.BasePermissionEvaluator">
        <!-- <property name="user" ref="user"></property> -->
        <aop:scoped-proxy />
    </bean>

    <bean id="domainSettings" class="com.kayoner.multytanecy.DomainSettings"></bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/jsp" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Kayoner-Helpdesk</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <jsp-config>
    <taglib>
      <taglib-uri>http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans</taglib-uri>
      <taglib-location>
                /WEB-INF/tld/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            </taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    <taglib>
      <taglib-uri>http://www.springframework.org/schema/context</taglib-uri>
      <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/spring-context-3.0.xsd</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    <taglib>
      <taglib-uri>http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx</taglib-uri>
      <taglib-location>
                /WEB-INF/tld/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
            </taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    <taglib>
      <taglib-uri>http://www.springframework.org/schema/task</taglib-uri>
      <taglib-location>
                /WEB-INF/tld/spring-task-3.0.xsd
            </taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    <taglib>
      <taglib-uri>http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc</taglib-uri>
      <taglib-location>
                /WEB-INF/tld/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
            </taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    <taglib>
      <taglib-uri>http://tiles.apache.org/dtds</taglib-uri>
      <taglib-location>
                /WEB-INF/lib/tiles-config_2_0.dtd
            </taglib-location>
    </taglib>
  </jsp-config>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.kayoner.Sessions.SessionListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml,
            /WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>3600</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/hesk/errors/errorCode404.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/hesk/errors/errorCode403.jsp</location>
  </error-page> 
   <error-page>
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/hesk/errors/errorCode403.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>405</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/hesk/errors/errorCode405.jsp</location>
  </error-page> 
  <error-page>
    <exception-type>org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/hesk/errors/errorCode505.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <exception-type>org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/hesk/errors/errorCode505.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.ClassFormatError</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/hesk/errors/catchError.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
 <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.kayoner.multytanecy.CustomSpringSecurityFilterChain</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <!-- <filter>
    <filter-name>HeaderFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.kayoner.multytanecy.HeaderFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>HeaderFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping> -->
</web-app>
```

Please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Make sure that the bean insatnce you are using is managed by Spring and in the same context as the `<task:annotation-driven />`. If your bean `SendMail` is in the `ContextLoaderListener` instead of the `DispachterServlet` (judging by the name of the XML) it isn't going to work.

Comment: please tell me which changes that i need to change?

Comment: Read the comment and check your configuration.

Comment: Please elaborate comment. I am not able to understood it.

Comment: The `<task:annotation-driven .. />` needs to be in the same application context as where you load your beans. If it is in the parent or child it will not work.

Comment: I edit my spring-servelt.xml file in my question. Can you tell me that is this current or not?

Comment: Without the other configuration it is hard to tell. My guess is that you have another xml, loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`, which is also scanning for the same components, effectivly duplicating your beans and rendering part of your configuration useless.

Comment: i also put my web.xml file. I have only two xml file for configuration. If you can help plase?